# As a service provider in SSO (SAML 2.0), should I generate X509 certificate for each client?

Tags: laravel, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I have implemented SAML as Service Provider in the project (PHP, Laravel). And now, we want to release it so that customers can use it. My question is, should i provide one certificate to all the clients or create new certificate for each clients? Why and why not?

Comment: What do you mean by client ? IDP ?

Comment: Yes, I mean the IDP.

Comment: a SAML entityID only needs one signing certificate. All IdPs use the public key from it to validate the SP